# How can I simulate time series a) with unit root and (b) near stationary and test ADF

Tags: r

Hi I would like to simulate eg AR(1) with 1000 repetitions a) with unit root and (b) near stationary and then apply to ADF test. I tried to do it in R and Gretl, but i do not know how to do all just in R.

My code is: for stationary TS

```
a1=runif(1, min=0.5, max=0.8)
aseries=arima.sim(list(ar=c(a1)),1000)
```

or for non-stationary TS

```
a2=arima.sim(n=1000, list(ar=0.5))
```

then i tried adf.test(a1)

but is not working, can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

In an `AR(1)` process the coefficient in absolute is always smaller than one, so the process is always stationary. You can simulate stationary time series of length 100 1000 times and apply the adf (only p-values extracted in the example) test as follows:

```
library(tseries)
set.seed(123)
st <- replicate(1000, arima.sim(model = list(ar = .99), n = 100))
pv.st <- apply(st, 2, function(x) adf.test(x)$p.value)

# The percentages of wrong decisions in case of nearly stationary processes (in this case, the decision is wrong if you do not reject the null hypothesis):
sum(pv.st > .01)/1000*100
[1] 99
sum(pv.st > .05)/1000*100
[1] 94.9
sum(pv.st > .1)/1000*100
[1] 89.6
```

If the coefficient equals one, it is no longer an `AR(1)` process, but a random walk. You can simulate it and apply the adf test to it as follows:

```
set.seed(123)
rw <- replicate(1000, cumsum(rnorm(100)))
pv.rw <- apply(rw, 2, function(x) adf.test(x)$p.value)

# The percentages of wrong decisions in case of non-stationary processes (in this case, the decision is wrong if you reject the null hypothesis):
 sum(pv.rw <= .01)/1000*100
[1] 1.4
> sum(pv.rw <= .05)/1000*100
[1] 5.3
> sum(pv.rw <= .1)/1000*100
[1] 9.4
```

Note, the null hypothesis of an adf-test ist non-stationarity, so if you reject it, this is a sign that the process *is* stationary, but if you cannot reject it, you cannot be sure it is stationary.

Comment: I know that AR(1) is stationary process, if condition of the coefficient are met. But I mean that simulate AR(1) process (a)RW and (b) with near stationary so coefficient is 0.99. Thank you for your help. I do not know, but your second line of the code is not working. Could you please help me, how to test ADF and compute the percentage of "wrong decisions" of the test (at 1%, 5% and 10%)?

Comment: @BarboraŠimková the package "tseries" must be loaded before running the second line of the code. If still not working, please give some details, do you get an error message? if so, what is the message?

Comment: @BarboraŠimková I modified my answer

Comment: > library(tseries)
> set.seed(123)
> st <- replicate(1000, arima.sim(model = list(ar = .99), n = 100))
> pv.st <- apply(st, 2, function(x) adf.test(x)$p.value)
There were 29 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In adf.test(x) : p-value greater than printed p-value
2: In adf.test(x) : p-value greater than printed p-value
3: In adf.test(x) : p-value greater than printed p-value
4: In adf.test(x) : p-value smaller than printed p-value

Comment: I get these warnings too. They are not critical, you can ignore them

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your help. I am beginner in R.

Comment: Do you mean vote up? I d be glad to do that, but i havent able to do that, because i have just 5 reputations and you are able to vote up from 15 reputations. Or do you mean something else?:)